# How to navigate from one template to another in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

My app has two kinds of templates. The first is used in "logged out" pages and the second one is used in "logged in" pages.

Below is the index.html which is used with all "logged out" template pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appLoggedOut">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Services 4 Uber</title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <script src="js/loggedout/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loggedout/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loggedout/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loggedout/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loggedout/directives.js"></script>

    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 15px;"></div>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </div>
    <div class="bar bar-footer bar-dark">
        Footer for Logged out pages
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to set all my "logged in" pages to show a header and a different footer. So, it is like I have another index.html, used just for "logged in" pages.

Below is the what I want to use to all my "logged in" pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appLoggedIn">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Services 4 Uber</title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <script src="js/loggedin/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loggedin/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loggedin/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loggedin/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loggedin/directives.js"></script>

    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    <div class="bar bar-header bar-light">
        Header used only in logged in pages
    </div>

    <div>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </div>

    <div class="bar bar-footer bar-dark">
        Footer for logged in pages
    </div>    

  </body>
</html>
```

How can I define my routes, to jump from my login page (using "logged out" template) to a logged page (using "logged in" template) ?

I want to change all the page and not just load a view inside the tag "".

Thanks.

Comment: I think you do not understand how ionic works. I am sorry, but your approach does not make any sense. You just need **one** `index.html` and your content is rendered by `ionic/angularjs` depending on your `"states"/"templates"`, e.g. login/logoff. Have a look at the templates on the [ionic starting page](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) and try to adapt it for you...

Comment: Hi, I understood the ionic works. My doubt is simple. I need that: first page with index.html using <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view> and a template with the view content. In it, a link to jump to a second page. In this second page, I need everything different. I do not wanna use the index.html. I wanna use another page with the tags <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view> (another main page) and another template page with view content. I do not wanna navigate using only the index.html main page. Is it clear now ?

Answer (score 1):

i am only discuss about the How to navigate from one template to another.
ionic that used angularjs or javaScript. is follow the simple call by **state or url etc**
for example Each controller have routing and there HTML page

```
angular.module('starter.storeDetailsController', [])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('storeDetails', {
            url: '/user/:store',
            abstract:true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/store_detail.html',
            controller: 'StoreDetailsCtrl'
        })
})

.controller('StoreDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicLoading',   '$timeout', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $timeout) {
     $scope.goToNextPage=function(){
        $state.go('home'); //here navigate from one template to another
     }
  }])
```

And another page

```
angular.module('starter.homeDetailsController', [])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            abstract:true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        })
})

     .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicLoading', '$timeout',    function($scope, $ionicLoading, $timeout) {
   console.log('Welcome');
}])
```

above example show two controller StoreDetailsCtrl and HomeCtrl and i go from StoreDetailsCtrl to HomeCtrl in home page. this is navigate by javascript but there are many ways to navigate page.

in HTML side by href=#/url and also used  ui-sref="stateName" in ionic for navigate page.

Comment: Hi Anurag. Yes this is part of my problem. I have already implemented that. But my doubt has another part. The destination page is still using the main index.html. I want to jump to the second page, and this one is using another kind of index.html. So, in the origin, I have my index,html with ion-nav-view and a template page with the view content. In the page target, I have another main page with ion-nav-view using other controls and a template page using this second main page. How to do that ?